# Check if the OS is up after bootstrap process

Tags: linux, shell, loops, operating-system

Im using racadm command to boot up and new node with RHEL7

This OS boot up is a part of other automation(first step)

Im using ansible for the whole automation, but Im basically using this code right now

```
- name: Test if the OS is up
  shell: |
    until ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null user@10.10.10.10 exit; do sleep 30; done
    echo Node node is up!
```

But this is not happenning cos right after the node comes up there is no user 'user' I need some commands like ping or any other approach to test and see if the node is up or not, any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ansible `wait_for_connection` module - Waits until remote system is reachable. Please check the documentation here
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html

This module makes use of internal ansible transport (and configuration) and the ping/win_ping module to guarantee correct end-to-end functioning